# Connection to Mongodb rejected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m new to React and Node and even though couple of days there was no error in my code, today I started to get an error in my terminal and I can not connect to my mongo database. I run my server with node server.js command but I get the error. Anyone can help to find a solution for this? Thanks!

ERROR

> Server is running on port 5000
>   (node:3339) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
>   (node:3339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-z8g0w.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cluster0-shard-00-00-z8g0w.mongodb.net:27017 closed
>       at TLSSocket. (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:372:9)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at net.js:659:12
>       at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:481:7) {
>     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   }]
>       at Pool. (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:433:11)
>       at Pool.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at /Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:577:14
>       at /Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1021:9
>       at callback (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:93:5)
>       at /Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:113:7
>       at _callback (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:320:5)
>       at Connection.errorHandler (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:336:5)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at TLSSocket. (/Users/petka/Desktop/react-recipesnew/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:370:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
>       at net.js:659:12
>       at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:481:7)
>   (node:3339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:3339) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const server = http.createServer(app)

//create the socket using the service instance
const io = socketIO(server)

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('New user connected.')

    socket.on('infoEvent', (information) => {
        console.log(`Information received: ${information}`)
        io.sockets.emit('infoEvent', information)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected')
    })
})


require('dotenv').config();


const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser:true, useCreateIndex:true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
//when the connection is open
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection established successfully")
})
const userrecipesRouter = require('./routes/userrecipes');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

//require and use the files route
app.use('/userrecipes', userrecipesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: where is your db hosted? Is it still running / healthy?

Answer (score 1):

try to connect like this:

```java
mongoose.connect(
    uri, 
    { 
        useNewUrlParser:true, 
        useCreateIndex:true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true //add this option
    }
);
```

Comment: What does this do exactly?